# Laravel Yajra datatables not installing

Tags: laravel, yajra-datatable

I am using  "yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle": "~9.0", however I keep getting error 
Class 'Yajra\DataTables\DataTablesServiceProvider' not found , i tried switching to lower case 't' in datatables , however it is still showing me 
Class 'Yajra\DataTables\DataTablesServiceProvider' not found

I have tried to run php artisan config:cache, php artisan cache:clear. all is still showing me Class 'Yajra\DataTables\DataTablesServiceProvider' not found

Kindly advise

config/app.php

```
 Yajra\DataTables\DataTablesServiceProvider::class,
 'Datatables' => Yajra\DataTables\Facades\DataTables::class,
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

run this:

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=datatables
```

also, check [this link](https://yajrabox.com/docs/laravel-datatables/master/installation) for more information

Answer (score 0):

Run

```
$ php artisan clear-compiled

$ composer dump-autoload

$ php artisan optimize:clear
```

and check

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you're importing the DataTable class with the correct upper/lower case in your files, lowercase since you're creating that way the alias `Datatables`